# Fastest Extension for a Chat Screen?

Tags: android, chat

I'm already making my chat screen and my requirements about this page are:

1. Fast opening and closing
2. Previous activity keeps working
3. Can change its view fast

In my Opinion Activity is too slow for that and startActivityForResult method is even slower. The options that come in my mind are fragments and dialoges, but wondered what is experienced guys opinion to share if you will please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please define "keeps working". Would it be enough to keep the bottom activity still visible under a transparent background? Also are you sure you're measuring the right thing? Are you sure your ListView is not your bottleneck? What about the open source application SMS Popup? does that application open fast enough for you? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup